# Access Redux state using React Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following Navigator using [React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/):

```
const Navigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home
    },
    User: {
      screen: User
    }
  }
)
```

And my `User` component:

```
export default class User extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: () => 'User'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>This is the user page.</Text>
    )
  }
}
```

I want the title of the `User` scene's navigation bar to be the user's name. The name is kept within the Redux state.

Since I'm accessing the `User` scene from the `Home` scene, I could pass the user's name when I push the scene:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('User', {name: user.name})
```

However if the user's name is updated when on the `User`, then the navigation title will not be updated. The only solution I can see is to access the Redux state from within `navigationOptions`. Is there a way to do this or a better way to handle this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found 2 solutions to my answer from an [issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/313) on react-navigations GitHub repo.

**1) Update this.props.navigation.state every time the props change:**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.totalCharge) {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ totalCharge });
  }
}
```

**2) Create a NavigationTitle component that is connected to the Redux state:**

```
static navigationOptions = {
  title: (navigation) => <MyConnectedTitle navigation={navigation} />
}
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps()` will be deprecated, warnings are introduced in release 16.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are calling

`this.props.navigation.navigate('User', {name: user.name})`

from a component. Therefore you should `mapStateToProps` in the component with the user's name and then pass it as the `{name: ...` variable.

For instance:

```
export class Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('User', {name: this.props.userName})}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userName: state.user.name
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)
```